# How to create a ColorSlider by picking start and end color in hexdec in android

Tags: android, seekbar, color-picker

I want to create a seekbar in Android which the startcolor is going to be for example "00AA10" and endcolor "0FFF99" and then I can change the color by incrementing this hex decimal value and get the new color by calculating the distance of the 2 given colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String hexString= "00AA10";
 int a=Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
 //if you want increment by 5 means i++ replace i=i+5
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
 i= a+i;
 String incHex = Integer.toHexString(i);
 seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+incHex));
 }
```

Comment: what if, I want to Calculate the color at a given point on a gradient between two colors?

Answer (score 0):

```
String hexStringStart= "00AA10";
int a=Integer.parseInt(hexStringStart, 16);

String hexStringEnd= "0FFF99";
int b=Integer.parseInt(hexStringEnd, 16);
int discrete=0;
int start_pos=0;
int start_position=0;
int start=0;
int end=100;
SeekBar seek= new SeekBar(getContext());
start=a;      // need to give starting value of SeekBar
end=b;         // need to give end value of SeekBar
start_pos=a;    // need to give starting position value of SeekBar

    start_position=(int) (((start_pos-start)/(end-start))*100);
    discrete=start_pos;
     seek.setProgress(start_position);
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            String colorString = String.format("%06X", (0xFFFFFF & discrete));
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Color = "+colorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // To convert it as discrete value
            float temp=progress;
            float dis=end-start;
            discrete = (int) (start+((temp/100)*dis));

        }
    });

}
```